# How do I properly receive UTF-8 characters in JBoss 7?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, jboss, request, jboss7.x

I’m using JBoss 7.1.3.  Currently, when I submit a request to the server with a special character, for example

```
Café
```

it is received by the server as

```
CafÃ©
```

The only piece of advice I found online for correcting this was to add these sysmte properties to $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml …

```
<system-properties>
    …
    <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```

However, even after restarting my server my special characters are still being received incorrectly on the server side.  What else can I do to properly interpret the characters?

Comment: how are you sending request

Comment: The request is being sent via the POST method

Comment: Are you in control of both server and client? Use SoapUI and send request, how does to server respond? Just to be sure it's the server 'fault.

Comment: Is the client adding the Content-Type header to the request that includes the encoding of UTF-8?  For instance `application/json; charset=utf-8`.  Furthermore, you'll need to make sure that on the server side those strings are being interpreted as bytes encoded in UTF-8 format.  If you are actually using JSON, UTF-8 is the de facto standard for all strings in the json format.  I still recommend explicitly sending the header with charset.  If you can confirm both of those things, I would look to your persistence layer.  Is there a problem with the database, for instance...

Comment: FWIW, those properties you mentioned above are used if you actually have UTF-8 chars embedded in the URL or in URL query strings

Comment: You should add the source code corresponding to the request sending.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that fixed the *encoding* for me for the ***JBOSS versions 7.1.0 beta or higher*** was to include the following line to the `standalone.conf` file **directly under the bin**

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING=UTF-8"
```

**OR**

Try the following in the `standalone.conf` **directly under bin** or `domain.conf` whichever might suit you

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

*Works for version **7.1 JBOSS**

Answer (score 0):

The e-acute is U+00E9.
Encoding using UTF-8, you get 0xC3 0xA9.
If you convert that on the assumption that your terminal or whatever is using cp1252 or similar, you get Ã©. Solution: don't do that. Tell your jboss to use UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

have you tries following option?

set start up param ,

```
-Dorg.wildfly.undertow.ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS_IN_URL=true
```

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-13710

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING` to `false`.

Had the same problem very recently, the above config being true was the core issue on **Jboss EAP 6.4.0**.

It seems that no matter what you set in `URI_ENCODING`, if `USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING` is set to true (and body has no encoding) it will default to **ISO-8859-1**.

As in tomcat docs: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html (look for `useBodyEncodingForURI` connector attribute).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in JBoss 6.4. JVM was correctly set, displaying special characters was ok, but the POST requests were encoded in **ISO-8859-1**.

Someone put a filter which set the encoding without luck.

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

In the end the issue was that this filter was not the first to be executed. What I did what to put this "UTF8 filter" in the first position and it solved the issue.
The trick is that the fist filter executed set the encoding. It seems that another filter did set the wrong encoding.

The class implements **javax.servlet.Filter** with the following code:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest inRequest, ServletResponse inResponse, FilterChain inFilterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    inRequest.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    inFilterChain.doFilter(inRequest, inResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Special Charaters don't recognize, I was using "ºª" and always arrived to server as Unicode Special Char as "�" , I resolved using a Filter in my application as:

```
if(String.contains("�"))
{
//here replace example with "?";
}
```